# Does weak convergence implies convergence in measure when $\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\|f_n\|_{L^p}<+\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f_n,f\colon [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be integrable functions satisfying $\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}\|f_n\|_{L^p}<+\infty$, where $p>1$.
If, for all measurable set $A\in \mathcal{B}[0,1]$,
$$\int\limits_{A}f_n d\mu\rightarrow\int\limits_{A}fd\mu, $$
is it true that $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in measure?

Comment: Are you sure about your second condition ? It seems like it gives you that $f_n=f$ almost everywhere on $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: I think $f_n(x)=\cos(nx)$ serves as a counterexample.

Comment: @Velobos could you show how to prove $f_n=f$ almost everywhere?

Comment: I guess there's a limit missing in the displayed equation. @Billchen

Comment: @Billchen, do we have $\int_A f_n d\mu = \int_A f d\mu$ or $\int_A f_n d\mu \to \int_A f d\mu$? It's written the first version, but in this case $f_n = f$ a.e.

Comment: @Billchen, it's not a full answer, but may be useful: math.stackexchange.com/questions/3029399. Under a stronger assumption of monotone convergence of integrals we can prove a more strong property: $f_n \to f$ a.e.

Comment: @BotnakovN. Could you help tell some more on how to derive "monotonity" in my problem? thanks

Comment: @Billchen, there's no monotonity in your problem. I mentioned another problem just because it's solution may contain smth. useful.

Comment: @BotnakovN. I am still confused, could you help me more?

Comment: @Billchen, I will write the answer if I'll solve the problem. To help you I may say that such keywords as "Inverse of Scheffe lemma", "convergence of Radon-Nikodym derivative" may be useful, and a book "Convergence of probability measures" by Billingsley also. By the way, do you suppose that $\mu$ is finite?

Comment: @BotnakovN. YES,$\mu$ is finite